# Insert text into word without converting to a paragraph

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

Below is a string which I have

```
    String def = "R. (12) Blessed the people the Lord has chosen to be his own.\r\n"
            + "Blessed the nation whose God is the LORD,\r\n"
            + "the people he has chosen for his own inheritance.\r\n" + "From heaven the LORD looks down;\r\n"
            + "he sees all mankind.\r\n" + "R. Blessed the people the Lord has chosen to be his own.\r\n"
            + "From his fixed throne he beholds\r\n" + "all who dwell on the earth,\r\n"
            + "He who fashioned the heart of each,\r\n" + "he who knows all their works.\r\n"
            + "R. Blessed the people the Lord has chosen to be his own.\r\n" + "Our soul waits for the LORD,\r\n"
            + "who is our help and our shield,\r\n" + "For in him our hearts rejoice;\r\n"
            + "in his holy name we trust.\r\n" + "R. Blessed the people the Lord has chosen to be his own.";
```

I am using the Apache POI library to insert this string into a word document

```
XWPFParagraph paragraph8 = document.createParagraph();
XWPFRun run8 = paragraph8.createRun();
run8.setText(def);
```

I want the text in the word in the below format

```
R. (12) Blessed the people the Lord has chosen to be his own.
Blessed the nation whose God is the LORD,
the people he has chosen for his own inheritance.
From heaven the LORD looks down;
he sees all mankind.
R. Blessed the people the Lord has chosen to be his own.
From his fixed throne he beholds
all who dwell on the earth,
He who fashioned the heart of each,
he who knows all their works.
R. Blessed the people the Lord has chosen to be his own.
Our soul waits for the LORD,
who is our help and our shield,
For in him our hearts rejoice;
in his holy name we trust.
R. Blessed the people the Lord has chosen to be his own.
```

But I am getting it as a paragraph

```
R. (12) Blessed the people the Lord has chosen to be his own. Blessed the nation whose God is the LORD, the people he has chosen for his own inheritance. From heaven the LORD looks down; he sees all mankind. R. Blessed the people the Lord has chosen to be his own. From his fixed throne he beholds all who dwell on the earth, He who fashioned the heart of each, he who knows all their works. R. Blessed the people the Lord has chosen to be his own. Our soul waits for the LORD, who is our help and our shield, For in him our hearts rejoice; in his holy name we trust. R. Blessed the people the Lord has chosen to be his own.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**\r\n** is not Word syntax for a line break. It can be helpful to set a few lines in Word, then examine the XML. You've been trying to set the entire passage as 1 run in 1 paragraph. If each line ends with a soft return, each line will be in a separate run:

```
<w:p w14:paraId="52A70B3B" w14:textId="21AEAB8E" w:rsidR="00A934F5" w:rsidRDefault="00BD29B4" w:rsidP="00BD29B4">
    <w:r>
        <w:t>R. (12) Blessed the people the Lord has chosen to be his own.</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:br/>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:t>Blessed the nation whose God is the LORD,</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:br/>
    </w:r>
```

If each line is separate by a hard return, each line will be a separate paragraph:

```
<w:p w14:paraId="21B22AC3" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="009023FF" w:rsidRDefault="009023FF" w:rsidP="009023FF">
    <w:r>
        <w:t>Blessed the nation whose God is the LORD,</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p w14:paraId="44B230A2" w14:textId="09D2C1FA" w:rsidR="009023FF" w:rsidRDefault="009023FF" w:rsidP="009023FF">
    <w:r>
        <w:t>the people he has chosen for his own inheritance.</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```